# Filter by testng group jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins

I have various test groups for my tests (P1, P2, P3, etc...). I also have the [TestNG plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/testng-plugin) installed on Jenkins.

I've dug through the source code of the TestNG plugin, and I've found that [there is a way to get the groups a test belongs to](https://github.com/jenkinsci/testng-plugin-plugin/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=getGroups&type=Code).

What I want is a way to filter my views on Jenkins to only display tests that belong to certain groups. Is this possible?

Comment: probably you need to create your own xml report or html report 
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/testng/testng-html-xml-reports-example/

Comment: You want to run all but print only few ..is it?

Comment: @shutdown-hnow Creating my own report won't help. I need a Jenkins view to display jobs of a certain test group.

Comment: @niharika_neo This doesn't involve printing. I need a Jenkins view to display jobs of a certain test group.

Comment: then you need use XML-RPC for jenkins to connect it